# $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log \left(\cosh\left(x^2-xc\right) \right)}{x^2}=\frac{c^2}{2}$ without L'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to show that without using L'Hospital's rule
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{\log \left(\cosh\left(x^2-xc\right) \right)}{x^2}=\frac{c^2}{2}
\end{align}

I was able to show the upper bound by using the bound $\cosh(x) \le e^{x^2/2}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log \left(\cosh\left(x^2-xc\right) \right)}{x^2} \le \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\left(x^2-xc\right)^2}{2x^2}=\frac{c^2}{2}
\end{align}

My question: How finish this argument.

Comment: Can you use Taylor's theorem?

Answer (score 7):

**PRIMER:**

In [This Answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263) , I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the exponential and logarithm functions satisfies the inequalities

$$1+x\le e^x\le \frac{1}{1-x} \tag 1$$

for $x<1$, and

$$\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1 \tag 2$$

for $x>0$,respectively.

It can also be shown that

$$|\sinh(x)|\ge |x| \tag 3$$

for all $x$.

---

**METHODOLOGY $1$: DEVELOPING A USEFUL LOWER BOUND**

> **The OP has expressed a preference to finding a useful lower bound for the function of interest.  To that end, we proceed.**

If we wish to find a lower bound then we can apply $(2)$ and $(3)$ and proceed to write

$$\begin{align}
\log(\cosh(x^2-cx)) &=\log\left(1-(1-\cosh(x^2-cx))\right)\\\\
&=\log\left(1+2\sinh^2\left(\frac{x^2-cx}{2}\right)\right)\\\\
&\ge \frac{2\sinh^2\left(\frac{x^2-cx}{2}\right)}{1+2\sinh^2\left(\frac{x^2-cx}{2}\right)}\\\\
&\ge \frac{2\left(\frac{x^2-cx}{2}\right)^2}{1+2\sinh^2\left(\frac{x^2-cx}{2}\right)}\tag 4
\end{align}$$

Then, dividing $(4)$ by $x^2$ we find that

$$\frac{\log(\cosh(x^2-cx))}{x^2}\ge \frac12 \frac{(x-c)^2}{1+2\sinh^2\left(\frac{x^2-cx}{2}\right)} \tag 5$$

The limit of the right-hand side of $(5)$ approaches $\frac{c^2}2$ as $x\to 0$

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$: APPLYING TAYLOR'S THEOREM**

> **The OP has stated that application of Taylor's is an acceptable way forward.  To that end, we proceed.**

Note from Taylor's Theorem,

$$\cosh(s)=1+\frac12s^2+O(s^4)\tag6$$

and

$$\log(1+t)=t-\frac12t^2+O(t^4) \tag7$$

Using $(6)$ and $(7)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\log(\cosh(x^2-cx))&=\log\left(1+\frac12(x^2-cx)^2+O((x^2-cx)^4)\right)\\\\
&=\frac12(x^2-cx)^2+O((x^2-cx)^4)\tag 8
\end{align}$$

Dividing $(8)$ by $x^2$ as taking the limit as $x\to 0$, we obtain the coveted limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(\cosh(x^2-cx))}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac12(x^2-cx)^2+O((x^2-cx)^4)}{x^2}=\frac{c^2}{2}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: @Boby Yes, I've edited to introduce these inequalities.  -Mark

Comment: The formula (3) $\sinh x\ge x$ for all $x$ is not true (for negative $x$).

Comment: @A.Γ. You're right.  But $|\sinh(x)|\ge x$ and thus $\sinh^2(x)\ge x^2$.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 5):

Denote $a=x^2-cx$ for simplicity. Then
\begin{align}
\frac{\ln(\cosh a )}{x^2}&=\frac{\ln(\cosh^2a)}{2x^2}=\color{blue}{\frac{\ln(1+\sinh^2a)}{2x^2}}=\frac12\cdot\frac{\ln(1+\sinh^2a)}{\sinh^2a}\cdot\left(\frac{\sinh a}{x}\right)^2=\\
&=\frac12\cdot\frac{\ln(1+\sinh^2a)}{\sinh^2a}\cdot\left(\frac12\cdot\left[\frac{e^a-1}{a}+\frac{e^{-a}-1}{-a}\right]\cdot\frac{a}{x}\right)^2\to\frac{c^2}{2}.
\end{align}

---

P.S. If you want a lower bound then using the inequality $e^a-1\ge a$ we can estimate
$$
\sinh^2 a=\left(\frac12\left[\frac{e^a-1}{a}+\frac{e^{-a}-1}{-a}\right]\right)^2a^2\ge a^2
$$
and continue from the blue expression above as
$$
\color{blue}{\frac{\ln(1+\sinh^2a)}{2x^2}}\ge\frac{\ln(1+a^2)}{2x^2}=\frac12\cdot\frac{\ln(1+a^2)}{a^2}\cdot\frac{a^2}{x^2}\to \frac{c^2}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that below we have used well-known limits $$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ { \left( 1+x \right)  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  } } =e\\ \lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { { e }^{ x }-1 }{ x }  } =1$$

> $$\lim _{ x\to 0 } \frac { \log  \left( \cosh  \left( x^{ 2 }-xc \right)  \right)  }{ x^{ 2 } } =\lim _{ x\to 0 } \frac { \log  \left( \frac { { e }^{ 2x^{ 2 }-2xc }+1 }{ 2{ e }^{ x^{ 2 }-xc } }  \right)  }{ x^{ 2 } } =\\ =\lim _{ x\to 0 }{ \log  \left( \frac { { e }^{ 2x^{ 2 }-2xc }+1 }{ 2{ e }^{ x^{ 2 }-xc } }  \right)  } ^{ \frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } }  }=\lim _{ x\to 0 }{ \log  \left( 1+\frac { { 1+e }^{ 2x^{ 2 }-2xc }-2{ e }^{ x^{ 2 }-xc } }{ 2{ e }^{ x^{ 2 }-xc } }  \right)  } ^{ \frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } }  }=\\ =\log { { e }^{ \lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { { 1+e }^{ 2x^{ 2 }-2xc }-2{ e }^{ x^{ 2 }-xc } }{ 2{ e }^{ x^{ 2 }-xc } } \cdot \frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } }  }  } } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { { 1+e }^{ 2x^{ 2 }-2xc }-2{ e }^{ x^{ 2 }-xc } }{ 2{ e }^{ x^{ 2 }-xc } } \cdot \frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { { \left( { e }^{ x^{ 2 }-xc }-1 \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ { \left( x^{ 2 }-xc \right)  }^{ 2 } } \cdot \frac { { \left( x^{ 2 }-xc \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ { 2{ e }^{ x^{ 2 }-xc }x }^{ 2 } }  } =\\ =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { { x }^{ 4 }-2c{ x }^{ 3 }+{ x }^{ 2 }{ c }^{ 2 } }{ { 2{ e }^{ x^{ 2 }-xc }x }^{ 2 } }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \left( \frac { { x }^{ 2 } }{ 2{ e }^{ x^{ 2 }-xc } } -\frac { cx }{ { e }^{ x^{ 2 }-xc } } +\frac { { c }^{ 2 } }{ 2{ e }^{ x^{ 2 }-xc } }  \right) = }\color{blue} {\frac { { c }^{ 2 } }{ 2 }} \\  $$

Comment: perhaps, but I haven't got any idea yet

Answer (score 3):

We can proceed as follows
\begin{align} 
L&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log\cosh(x^{2}-cx)}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log\cosh(x^{2}-cx)}{\cosh(x^{2}-cx)-1}\cdot\frac{\cosh(x^{2}-cx)-1}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sinh^{2}((x^{2}-cx)/2)}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}2\cdot\frac{\sinh^{2}((x^{2}-cx)/2)}{(x^{2}-cx)^{2}/4}\cdot\frac{x^{2}(x-c)^{2}}{4x^{2}}\notag\\
&=2\cdot 1\cdot\frac{c^{2}}{4}\notag\\
&=\frac{c^{2}}{2}\notag
\end{align}

Comment: Similar to my Methodology $1$, but without developing bounds.  (+1)

Comment: @Dr.MV: I was going to upvote your answer then you changed it on request of OP so I had to reread it. You are damn fast. +1 for the effort to meet the specific request of OP.

Comment: Paramanand, I appreciate that my friend!  You are truly one of the good people on the site.  -Mark

Answer (score 1):

Notice first that

$${\log(\cosh(x^2-xc))\over x^2}={\log(\cosh(x^2-xc))\over(x^2-xc)^2}(x-c)^2$$

Since $(x-c)^2\to c^2$ as $x\to0$, it suffices to show that

$$\lim_{x\to0}{\log(\cosh(x^2-xc))\over(x^2-xc)^2}=\lim_{u\to0}{\log(\cosh u)\over u^2}={1\over2}$$

But

$${2\log(\cosh u)\over u^2}={\log(\cosh^2u)\over u^2}={\log(1+\sinh^2u)\over u^2}={\log(1+\sinh^2u)\over\sinh^2u}\left(\sinh u\over u\right)^2$$

so it suffices to show that

$$\lim_{u\to0}{\log(1+\sinh^2u)\over\sinh^2u}=\lim_{v\to0}{\log(1+v)\over v}=1\qquad\text{and}\qquad\lim_{u\to0}{\sinh u\over u}=1$$

But these final two limits are just the derivatives of the functions $\log(1+x)$ and $\sinh x$ evaluated at $0$.  We are *not* using L'Hopital's rule in obtaining those limits.